# Django search field not working

Tags: python, django, search, django-models, django-views

I would like to be able to search for the user and have it direct me to a list of all users.

When I try the search function, I receive this error: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains.

It traces back to this line:

```
clients = LessonCount.objects.filter(user__icontains=q)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

***views.py:***

```
def search(request):
try:
    q = request.GET.get('q')
except:
    q = None

if q:
    clients = LessonCount.objects.filter(user__icontains=q)
    context = {
        'query': q, 
        'clients': clients
    }
    template = 'clients.html'
else:
    context = {}
    template = 'contact.html'
return render(request, template, context)
```

***models.py:***

```
class LessonCount(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
lesson_current_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Current Number of Lessons')

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user.username)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-user']

def update_lesson_count(self):
    if self.lesson_current_amount > 0:
        self.user.is_member = True
        self.user.save()
    elif self.lesson_current_amount <= 0:
        self.user.is_member = False
        self.user.save()
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(user__icontains=q)` is calling the icontains lookup on the user object. I think what you should be doing is `(user__username__icontains=q)` which will perform the lookup on the user's name.